# Heroku can't update CSS

Tags: git, jakarta-ee, heroku

I want to update my project on Heroku.

I have used:

```
git add .
git commit -m "aaa"
git push origin master
```

and then on Heroku website i deployed code from Github. Everything has been updated but CSS stayed not updated. Locally and on Github I can see new version of CSS file. What should i do? I have only found solutions for Ruby on Rails, not Java EE.

Comment: You will need to supply us with more information to help. Where are your CSS files stored? In your codebase? On a static file server somewhere? Do you have cache headers set on these files that might be affecting things? Have you tried wiping your browser cache? If you use the browser tools, can you see from where the CSS files are being loaded? Are you using any asset pipelines? Etc.

Comment: Sounds very much like a browser cache issue. Please try this on a different browser or computer and let us know what happens

Answer (score 3):

Heroku tends to hold onto cached versions of your site. If you clear your browser's cache it should fix this problem

Comment: Hello, please integrate your comment into answer so it becomes a full answer.